# JS engine processes the data, why it doesn't meet the expected value

Tags: javascript

I am testing the ability of the JS engine to handle different levels of data.
But this result surprised me.

```js
const step = [10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,1000000000];
let sum = 0;
step.forEach((item) => {
 let n = item.toString().split('').length -1;
 console.time(`10^${n}`);
 while (item){
  ++sum;
  --item;
 }
 console.timeEnd(`10^${n}`);
})
```

10^1 is slower than 10^3,or 10^5 is slower than 10^6,or both.

The runtime of the test includes：chrome71,node 10.13.0,firefox64(not so bad)

I don't know if this is the behavior of V8.

I followed *CertainPerformance*'s suggestion to use *performance.now()*

```js
// nodeJs
//const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

const step = [10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,1000000000];
let sum = 0;
step.forEach((item) => {
 let n = item.toString().split('').length -1;
 let t0 = performance.now();
 while (item){
  ++sum;
  --item;
 }
 let t1 = performance.now();
 console.log(`10^${n}：`,t1-t0);
})
```

It will appear more than a few times.

Comment: Millisecond timing isn't incredibly accurate IIRC, but yes, I can reproduce it too, 10^5 is often *slower* than 10^6, even with `performance.now`

Comment: What happens if you `step.reverse()` before?

Comment: @JonasWilms god,you are right,I have not been the performance of array access，

Answer (score 1):

You should run the code more than once, as the first time the code runs, it is never optimized, and while you're running this the JS engine starts optimizing parts of the code/function. And when you press "Run code snippet" again, it's technically a new code and the optimizer needs to start all over again.

You'll see that it is way more consistent after the first run:

And I'd not read too much into fluctuations in a range of <0.1ms and the resulting differences in order among the first items.

```js
const step = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000];
let sum = 0;
const test = (item) => {
  let n = item.toString().split('').length - 1;
  console.time(`10^${n}`);
  while (item) {
    ++sum;
    --item;
  }
  console.timeEnd(`10^${n}`);
};

const runTest = (times) => {
  if (times > 0) {
    sum = 0;
    step.forEach(test);
    console.log("----");
    setTimeout(runTest, 10, times - 1);
  }
}

runTest(10);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100%!important
}
```

Sidenote: you'll see that if you don't reset `sum = 0`, after a few runs the runtimes will go up. This is due to the fact that `sum` reaches a value where it is no longer representble as an `int` but instead is turned into a `double`. This makes not only `++sum` just so slightly more expensive, wich adds up due to the shere number of iterations, but it also negates the optimizers assumption of the type of `sum` in your code, wich results in a deopt of the code and after like 100-150 iterations (unoptimized) a re-optimization of the code under the new assumption that `sum` is either `int` or `double`, wich also makes `++sum` slightly slower than when it was just an `int`.

Comment: `as an int but instead is turned into a double` JS doesn't have ints vs doubles - it only has `number`s, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance JS doesn't have `ints` and `doubles`, but the underlying Engines nowadays do. JS' `Number` is technically a `double`, but why bother with that big and complicated format if an `int` is sufficiant? Like JS Objects are basically Dictionaries, but that's the least efficiant and slowest data structure you can use for that purpose, so modern JS engines use hidden classes to circumvent this problem as much as possible.